# Wierd NSArray Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is __NSArrayI and __NSArrayM? How to convert to NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684611/what-is-nsarrayi-and-nsarraym-how-to-convert-to-nsarray)

I am getting the error below

2012-06-06 15:53:19.509 NavApp[5462:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x353b788f 0x3775e259 0x3530c1d7 0xba3e5 0xc128b 0x32e2db95 0x32e87d85 0x32e4a251 0x32e49fa1 0x32e49cbb 0x32e49a2f 0x32e00aab 0x32e063d5 0x3220cc2f 0x34246ee7 0x3538a2ad 0x3530d4a5 0x3530d36d 0x36fa9439 0x32e19cd5 0x106a71 0xb8c70)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I think it's odd because it says "__NSArrayM"... Any idea what this means?

Comment: You are trying to insert nil into the array, which is not possible.

Comment: It means the documentation wasn't joking when it said NSArray was a class cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to insert a nil object to an NSMutableArray
This will cause an exception, since mutable array cannot contain nil objects

About the __NSArrayM

```
__NSArrayM is a NSMutableArray
__NSArrayI is a NSArray
```