# replace object in mutable array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

This should be rather easy and probably I'm just missing a small thing:
I have an array of images called defaultImages

```
NSMutableArray *defaultLetters;
```

then I add the letters needed (array length then is 42)

later I'm trying to replace one of the images in the array with another image. Like this:

```
[defaultLetters replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:croppedPhoto];
```

but I'm getting an error saying: "-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x180ae190"
is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: please show us, how you assign something to `defaultLetters`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you assign value like this

```
defaultLetters = anotherMutableArray;
```

If you do like this, then please replace as below..

```
defaultLetters = [anotherMutableArray mutableCopy];
```

Ater you can replace object in that array

```
[defaultLetters replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:croppedPhoto];
```

Try this..Because if you directly assign you can't insert or remove.

Answer (score 7):

You assigned a `NSArray` object to `defaultLetters`, not a `NSMutableArray`.

`__NSArrayI` is a private Subclass of NSArray. The `I` stands for immutable.

see [What is __NSArrayI and __NSArrayM? How to convert to NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684611/what-is-nsarrayi-and-nsarraym-how-to-convert-to-nsarray)

---

if you can't tell for sure, if it is an NSArray or an NSMutableArray you are assigning, you can always test.

```
if(![defaultLetters respondsToSelector:@selector(replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:)]){
    defaultLetters = [defaultLetters mutableCopy];
}
```

But this might indicate an architectural issue within your code, as you should know for certain what objects you are dealing with.