# Trying to extract advertised serviceUUID from BLE advertisementData

Tags: key, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

My peripheral advertises one serviceUUID as part of the advertisementData.  I want the advertised serviceUUID without connecting. Here is my code:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

        peripherals.append(peripheral)

        let serviceUUID = [advertisementData: CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]

        print(serviceUUID)
    }
```

When my code runs I see this in the console:

```
    {
        {
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataLocalName = "sensor ID not set up yet";
        kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =         (
            "926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
        );
    } = kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs;
}
```

I am after the "926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".  Any ideas how to get it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is small bug in your code .

`let serviceUUID = [advertisementData: CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]` basically creates a new dictionary with a single key-value pair. The key is the original `advertisementData` dictionary and the corresponding value is `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` - which is what you see in your log.

What you want to do is:

`let serviceUUID = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a good question, because this is a real pain point: cryptic output in the debugger at the Swift/Obj-C intersection.

The actual issue is that the value returned by `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]` is an `NSArray`. How do I know?

```
(lldb) po advertisementData
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "kCBAdvDataIsConnectable"
    - value : 1
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"
    ▿ value : 1 element
      - 0 : 926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

(lldb) po advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    - 0 : 926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

OK so we see it's an optional. Add `!`:

```
(lldb) po advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]!
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : 926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

And we're back where we started. What the heck is this? Use [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type):

```
(lldb) po type(of:advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]!)
__NSArrayM
```

That cryptic type [means `NSMutableArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684642/1161906). So we need to cast the output to `NSArray` and index the array:

```
(lldb) po advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]! as! NSArray
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : 926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

(lldb) po (advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]! as! NSArray)[0]
926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

What's the type?

```
(lldb) po type(of:(advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]! as! NSArray)[0])
CBUUID
```

OK so we've got a `CBUUID`. We're done:

```
(lldb) po ((advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]! as! NSArray)[0]) as! CBUUID
926D74A0-D820-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

Ugh.